# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode referenced in function DriverEntry

Tags: windows, driver

I write a windows 10 driver.

following is the code, actually the code is a sample of learn.microsoft.com.

is there anyone know what shold i do to deal with this issue.

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>


DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd;


NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(
    _In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT     DriverObject,
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING    RegistryPath
)
{
    // NTSTATUS variable to record success or failure
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    // Allocate the driver configuration object
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;

    // Print "Hello World" for DriverEntry
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry\n"));

    // Initialize the driver configuration object to register the
    // entry point for the EvtDeviceAdd callback, KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config,
        KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd
    );

    // Finally, create the driver object
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject,
        RegistryPath,
        WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,
        &config,
        WDF_NO_HANDLE
    );
    return status;
}


NTSTATUS
KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd(
    _In_    WDFDRIVER       Driver,
    _Inout_ PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit
)
{
    // We're not using the driver object,
    // so we need to mark it as unreferenced
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    NTSTATUS status;

    // Allocate the device object
    WDFDEVICE hDevice;

    // Print "Hello World"
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd\n"));

    // Create the device object
    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit,
        WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,
        &hDevice
    );
    return status;
}
```

Help! if you have some suggestion, please let me know.

the error message is:

```
Driver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode referenced in function DriverEntry
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is related to the new [C++ Just My Code Stepping](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/06/29/announcing-jmc-stepping-in-visual-studio/) feature in Visual Studio 2017 15.8.

If you get the error open the Project Properties dialog box and set the "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Support Just My Code Debugging" option to no.

Comment: Please try to explain better your answer to make it easier to understand

Comment: Where can this option be found? Are you referring to the Options dialog box? If so, I cannot find this option. Using the Search feature in the Options dialog box I see "Enable Just My Code" in [Environment\General] but I do not see "c/c++ -> general ->support Just My Code Debuging." In fact, I do not see C++ at the top level in the Options dialog box at all.

Comment: I found it. You are referring to the Project Properties dialog box.

Answer (score 5):

This is related to the new C++ *Just My Code Stepping* (JMC) feature in Visual Studio 2017 15.8. Because the feature depends on CRT (C Run-Time Libraries), if the project does not link to CRT, it may hit `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode`.

The workaround is to disable JMC via one of the following methods:

1. in project settings, "Configuration Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "General": "Support Just My Code Debugging". Change to NO.
2. in project settings, add `/JMC-` to "Configuration Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "Command line" -> "Additional Options"

Comment: The visual studio community 2017 version 15.6.4 does not have this option - any suggestions on how to then deal with the issue?

Comment: Theoretically 15.6.4 does not have this feature. So you should not hit this link failure at all. If it's not the case, feel to file a ticket on Developer Community @ https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/62/index.html

Comment: the 15.6.4 does NOT have this feature, however what to do if a lib used is updated and now it has been build on a 15.8 version -- ofcourse updating to 15.8 would solve issue, but what if that was not possible? would it be possible to suppress this?

Comment: The issue is: compiler backend inserts a call function to __CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode, which exists in CRT. Old toolset (older that 15.8, eg 15.6) is not able to inserts this call. To suppress it, add /JMC- to the compiler switches during the build.

Comment: adding /JMC to older version just creates a message saying that switch is unknown - try it before suggesting it

Comment: Please note: I was suggesting "/JMC-", NOT "/JMC", which disables JMC feature explicitly.

Comment: sorry did not notice the "-" at the end, however disabling an unknown switch how would that help?

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 15.8 they introduced [JustMyCode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/06/29/announcing-jmc-stepping-in-visual-studio/) debugging, and it actually breaks compilation of a kernel drivers in debug configuration.

[It looks like a bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/302014/dirver-build-debugmode-checkfordebuggerjustmycode.html), but the workaround is to compile in release mode for now.

Comment: Actually the workaround is to disable that JustMyCode feature. [Unfortunately you have to do it for each and every project.](https://www.osr.com/blog/2018/08/30/baaack-just-code-part-ii-breaks-driver-debug-builds/)

Comment: I personally had to disable JustMyCode on a plugin I wrote for NSIS as this issue was triggered in the same way - I had removed the MSVCRT so that the plugin would be small (the binary prior to packing in the NSIS installer is 7680 bytes), Windows version independent, and not dependent on having the runtime already installed.

P.S.  Thanks for the advice, it helped make my VS2017 build work once again.